# Something adds a dot at the end of my Firebase query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have a List of favorites ID's, that I'm fetching from Firebase.
The first of the list is fetched normally, the problem is that on the second ID "something" adds a dot at the end of the string becoming "Vd$r367Tyuezjphk4699sd." from "Vd$r367Tyuezjphk4699sd"

The method I use is:

```
 _getFavorites(favorites) async {
    for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
      var id = favorites[i];
      print('HERE ID ID ID $id');
      final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('favorites').child(id);
      var snapshot = await dbRef.once();
```

the print('HERE ID ID ID $id'); gives the correct ID:

> HERE ID ID ID Vd$r367Tyuezjphk4699sd

and then the next output line is:

> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(2756979): Failed to
> handle method call
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_database(2756979):
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase
> Database path: favorites/Vd$r367Tyuezjphk4699sd.
>
> Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Anyone have an idea what's going on here? I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the issue is the dot(.) but the dollar symbol ($). It is in the error last line Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Just posted an answer like a minute ago.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems that the problem is the $ symbol not the dot. The dot is there to indicate the end of the sentence, but that "Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'" confused me and made me think, that the dot is the problem. Then I saw the $ in the given ID and it's there, because Ive added some dummy data.